# Sending email for Mailing List by MailGun

Tags: php, email, mailgun, mailing-list

Here  is my code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['sendButton'], $_POST['header'], $_POST['content'])){
    $message = $_POST['content'];
    $from = "emailForKursova@ukr.net";
    $subject = $_POST['header'];

    $mg->sendMessage($domain , [
      'from'    => $from,
      'to'      => 'testlist@sandbox394f17689b2b43a187f9ac506b00da4b.mailgun.org',  
      'subject' => $subject,
      'html'    => "{$message}<br><br><a href=\"%unsubscribe_url%\">Unsubscribe</a>"
    ]);
}
```

It does not works, returns an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters' with message 'The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.' in D:\Programs\Studying\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\www\Web2017_3k\Kursova_3_Kurs\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php:254 Stack trace: #0 D:\Programs\Studying\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\www\Web2017_3k\Kursova_3_Kurs\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(110): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->responseHandler(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 D:\Programs\Studying\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\www\Web2017_3k\Kursova_3_Kurs\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(179): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->send('POST', 'sandbox394f1768...', Array, Array) #2 D:\Programs\Studying\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localh in D:\Programs\Studying\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\www\Web2017_3k\Kursova_3_Kurs\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php on line 254

Help me please to solve my problem

Comment: The clue is in the error: "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings"

Comment: I have added the recipients to the list, but what means " own domain"?